# .NET vs Mono. What's the difference?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I've done a bit of reading online and I'm not seeing a straight forward answer to a straight forward question. Is .NET for Windows and Mono for Mac? Maybe my understanding is off but I'm trying to figure out the difference between the two tools. Thanks in advance.

Comment: .NET is Microsoft's "platform" or whatever it is, for windows. Mono is an "open source" implementation of .NET for assorted platforms. [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) on Mono seems like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Mono is a cross platform alternative implementation of the .NET Framework.

Comment: I'm not seeing a straight forward answer to a straight forward question; are Ford automobiles for the U.S. and green automobiles for the UK?

Comment: Thank you to everyone that responded. These responses did answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can accept an answer in such a case. I believe your question is fair.

Answer (score 4):

Mono was originally reimplementation of the .NET for linux. Today is much more (http://www.mono-project.com/).

There is actually funny story behind. Miguel De Icaza was working on linux email client and he loved .NET C# so much that we wanted to work with it also on linux. So he rewrite the .NET so he can wrote email client in C#. Wow.

Then mono evolved very very much all lead to the Xamarin platform (.NET cross mobile platform).

You can more read here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/27/net-core-1-0-net-framework-xamarin-the-whatand-when-to-use-it/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

.NET comes with a runtime environment that runs .NET apps on a windows based OS.  It is of course produced and distributed by Microsoft.  Mono is an open source version of the that which allows you to do this on Linux, Mac, and even windows.

Conceptually, the runtime seems to operate somewhat like a JRE does, in that, you can take a module built in .NET, and run it in Mono.   So, it must be something like byte code that can then be interpreted and compiled to run natively (this last sentence is all speculation).